# Test that Project Reference doesn't exist

Tags: c#, reflection, mstest

I have a Visual Studio solution with a number of projects.  Most projects are for internal/intranet use, but a small handful are for public facing websites.

For internal projects, I use a `ProjectName.Data` project with Entity Framework that access the database.

For the public projects, I use a different data access method which is only allowed to hit stored procedures in a certain schema.

As part of my integration/system testing, I want to ensure that these public projects *do not* have a reference to the `ProjectName.Data` project (e.g., make sure some dev didn't say *hey, there we go, I'll add a reference here and boom, easy access to the whole boat*).

As part of my MSTest project for this public facing, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Integration")]
public void CheckNoAccessToDataProject() {
    var ref = ProjectUnderTest.GetReference("ProjectName.Data");
    Assert.IsNull(ref);
}
```

I did find a way to possibly shoehorn this by using `Type.GetType("Full.Name.To.EF6.Context")` but I would much prefer to check the reference itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Roslyn for that. First install nuget package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common, then:

```
var solutionPath = @"path to your solution .sln file";
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
var dataProject = solution.Projects.First(c => c.Name == "ProjectName.Data");
var testProject = solution.Projects.First(c => c.Name == "NameOfProjectYouTest");
var hasReference = testProject.AllProjectReferences.Any(c => c.ProjectId == dataProject.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

To address the concern that you've described, you might want to consider one or a combination of other methods which might be better (and possibly easier to implement):

1) You can [create a **custom Visual Studio extension**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166030.aspx) that **prevents** such forbidden references **from being added in the first place** (through the UI, anyway).

2) You can check for such references in **pre-commit hooks** (script checks XML in .csproj files) so that even if they are added, they **never make it into source control**. Here are possible starting points for [Git](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/05/reduce-merge-conflicts-in-dot-net-solutions-with-powershell-based-git-hooks/) and [SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797942/svn-pre-commit-hook-to-ensure-all-files-referenced-in-csproj-are-versioned).

3) You can check for them in **code and pull-request reviews** -- this is a "process" solution rather than a technology one. This way, the references may get checked into a development branch, but they'd **never make it into a release branch**.

4) You can **catch them at build time with a [custom MSBuild task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx)/target**. The advantage here is that you'd arguably be operating at the ideal level of abstraction -- MSBuild is where project references are read, resolved, and used for compilation.

5) You can **catch them later at test execution time**, which is what you're trying to do. I wouldn't say it's bad to check for these errors at this stage, **but** naturally it would be **better to catch them earlier**, especially if the risk/cost of data exposure is high.

I don't know much about the Visual Studio object model, but here are some SO questions ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080625/updating-visual-studio-project-references-programatically), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530281/adding-programmatically-in-c-sharp-a-project-reference-as-opposed-to-an-assembl), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544354/how-to-programmatically-include-a-file-in-my-project), and [#4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410258/c-sharp-visual-studio-adding-references-programmatically)) and an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228960.aspx) that might help with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  We do pull requests and reviews as is, but figured it'd be one less thing to look for if I can prevent it elsewhere.  I typically try to avoid custom VS extensions, but handling via MSBuild really seems ideal - I should set something up there.